# You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks-Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have checked `react` and `react-dom` versions through `npm ls react-dom` and`npm ls react` and they are the same. I have also checked for another react but I only have 1.

**Index.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "./index.css";
    import App from "./App";
    import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
    import store from "./store";

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
       <React.StrictMode>
         <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );

    // If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
    // to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
```

**store.js**

```
  import { createStore } from "redux";
  import data from "./data";

  const initialState = {};
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
      return { products: data.products };
      };
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
  export default store;
```

**App.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import HomeScreen from "./Screens/HomeScreen";
    import ProductScreen from "./Screens/ProductScreen";

    function App() {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="grid-container">
            <header className="row">
              <div>
                <a className="brand" href="/">
                  amazona
                </a>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
                <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
              </div>
            </header>
            <main>
              <Route path="/product/:id" component= 
       {ProductScreen}></Route>
      <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact></Route>
    </main>
    <footer className="row center"> All right reserved</footer>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

    import Product from "../components/Product";
    import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
    import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";



      function HomeScreen(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
        setLoading(false);
        setProducts(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <div className="row center">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**ProductScreen.js**

```
 import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import data from "../data";
import Rating from "../components/Rating";

function ProductScreen(props) {
  const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id);
  if (!product) {
    return <div>Product Not Found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Back To Results</Link>
      <div className="row top">
        <div className=" col-2">
          <img className="large" src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
        </div>
        <div className="col-1">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Rating
                rating={product.rating}
                numReviews={product.numReviews}
              ></Rating>
            </li>
            <li>Price: KSh{product.price}</li>
            <li>
              Description:
              <p>{product.description}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-1">
          <div className="card card-body">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>Price</div>
                  <div className="price">KSh{product.price}</div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>Status</div>
                  <div>
                    {product.countInStock > 0 ? (
                      <span className="success">In Stock</span>
                    ) : (
                      <span className="danger">Unavailable</span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button className="primary block">Add to Cart</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

**Error**

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

index.js line 9

```
   6 | import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
   7 | import store from "./store";
   8 | 
>  9 | ReactDOM.render(
  10 |   <Provider store={store}>
  11 |     <React.StrictMode>
  12 |       <App />
```

Answer (score -1):

Rules of Hooks specify that hooks call can never be done in conditions.

In your code, you call hooks in try/catch which means they wont all run and thus breaks the fact that hooks needs to always be called in the same order.

See some more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20514)